# I want to make a list view like this image . So what layout would be suitable for this?

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, material-design

[image]

I want to make a `listview` like this image . So what layout would be suitable for this ?

I am using this xml code . Please tell me how can i get like this image . between two item of list is proper space is present .

list_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_row_selector"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <!-- Thumbnail Image -->
    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"  />

    <!-- Restaurant name  -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textSize="@dimen/title"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/area"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/name"
        android:textColor="#D2691E"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />

    <!-- Rating -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/average_ratings"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/area"
        android:textColor="#D2691E"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"

        android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cuisine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/average_ratings"
        android:textColor="#D2691E"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />

    <!-- Genre -->
   <!-- <TextView
        android:id="@+id/genre"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/rating"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textColor="@color/genre"
        android:textSize="@dimen/genre" />-->
<!--
    &lt;!&ndash; Release Year &ndash;&gt;
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/releaseYear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="@color/year"
        android:textSize="@dimen/year" />-->

</RelativeLayout>
```

using of this i am getting like this image .

[image]

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Comment: I want to say Thank you so much .

Comment: RecyclerView + CardView. OR (less performant) ListView + custom row item.

Comment: I want to say Thank you so much

Comment: @user6313669 glad to help you happy coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its called `card view` use `recycler view` to fetch the cards, Its very efficient than list view.

Link: https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Example app:http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/

Answer (score 2):

This is call [Cardview](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/android-l-recyclerview-and-cardview-tutorial/156)

In Gradle add this

```
dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.0-rc1'

 }
```

in your xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
      xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/card_view"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
      android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
```